# Substituir valor de um DATAFRAME, com lista, for e replace

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Tenho duas listas, uma com nome errado e outra com o nome correto, como fazer o REPLACE usando as listas e o FOR, esse código não funcionou:

Lista com o dados a serem corrigidos:

```
lista_original = ['ACREERONDONIA','AMAZONASERORAIMA','CEARA','ESPIRITOSANTO','GOIAS','MARANHAO','MATOGROSSO','MATOGROSSODOSUL','MINASGERAIS','OFEDERALETOCANTINS','PARAEAMAPA','PARAIBA','PARANA','RIODEJANEIRO','RIOGRANDEDONORTE','RIOGRANDEDOSUL','SANTACATARINA','SAOPAULO']
```

Lista com o dados corretos:

```
lista_corrigida = ['ACRE E RONDÔNIA','AMAZONAS E RORAIMA','CEARÁ','ESPÍRITO SANTO','GOIÁS','MARANHÃO','MATO GROSSO','MATO GROSSO DO SUL','MINAS GERAIS','DISTRITO FEDERAL E TOCANTINS','PARA E AMAPÁ','PARAÍBA','PARANÁ','PERNAMBUCO','PIAUI','RIO DE JANEIRO','RIO GRANDE DO NORTE','RIO GRANDE DO SUL','SANTA CATARINA','SÃO PAULO']
```

df_dados_txt - dataframe, criado para receber uma carga de dados de arquivo CSV (funcionando) - estrutura:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 714912 entries, 0 to 714911
Data columns (total 10 columns):
AGENCIA         714912 non-null object
NU_CONTA        714912 non-null object
DV              714912 non-null object
DT_ABERTURA     714912 non-null datetime64[ns]
PROCESSO        714912 non-null object
NU_PROCESSO     714912 non-null object
TRIBUNAL        714912 non-null object
LOCAL           714912 non-null object
VARA            714912 non-null object
CANAL_ORIGEM    714912 non-null object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), object(9)
memory usage: 54.5+ MB
```

Laço para fazer o replace:

```
for x in range(23):
        df_dados_txt['LOCAL'] = df_dados_txt['LOCAL'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(lista_original[x], lista_corrigida[x]))
```

Erro tomando:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Observação, assim funciona, mas eu gostaria de otimizar esse código:

```
df_dados_txt['LOCAL'] = df_dados_txt['LOCAL'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('ACREERONDONIA','ACRE E RONDÔNIA'))
df_dados_txt['LOCAL'] = df_dados_txt['LOCAL'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('AMAZONASERORAIMA', 'AMAZONAS E RORAIMA'))
df_dados_txt['LOCAL'] = df_dados_txt['LOCAL'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('CEARA', 'CEARÁ'))
df_dados_txt['LOCAL'] = df_dados_txt['LOCAL'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('ESPIRITOSANTO', 'ESPÍRITO SANTO'))
df_dados_txt['LOCAL'] = df_dados_txt['LOCAL'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('GOIAS', 'GOIÁS'))
df_dados_txt['LOCAL'] = df_dados_txt['LOCAL'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('MARANHAO', 'MARANHÃO'))
df_dados_txt['LOCAL'] = df_dados_txt['LOCAL'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('MATOGROSSO', 'MATOGROSSO'))
df_dados_txt['LOCAL'] = df_dados_txt['LOCAL'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('MATOGROSSODOSUL', 'MATO GROSSO DO SUL'))
df_dados_txt['LOCAL'] = df_dados_txt['LOCAL'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('MINASGERAIS', 'MINAS GERAIS'))
df_dados_txt['LOCAL'] = df_dados_txt['LOCAL'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('OFEDERALETOCANTINS', 'DISTRITO FEDERAL E TOCANTINS'))
df_dados_txt['LOCAL'] = df_dados_txt['LOCAL'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('PARAEAMAPA', 'PARÁ E AMAPÁ'))
df_dados_txt['LOCAL'] = df_dados_txt['LOCAL'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('PARAIBA', 'PARAÍBA'))
df_dados_txt['LOCAL'] = df_dados_txt['LOCAL'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('PARANA', 'PARANÁ'))
df_dados_txt['LOCAL'] = df_dados_txt['LOCAL'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('RIODEJANEIRO', 'RIO DE JANEIRO'))
df_dados_txt['LOCAL'] = df_dados_txt['LOCAL'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('RIOGRANDEDONORTE', 'RIO GRANDE DO NORTE'))
df_dados_txt['LOCAL'] = df_dados_txt['LOCAL'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('RIOGRANDEDOSUL', 'RIO GRANDE DO SUL'))
df_dados_txt['LOCAL'] = df_dados_txt['LOCAL'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('SANTACATARINA', 'SANTA CATARINA'))
df_dados_txt['LOCAL'] = df_dados_txt['LOCAL'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('SAOPAULO', 'SÃO PAULO'))
```

Comment: Alex, caso alguma das respostas abaixo tenha respondido sua pergunta, considere [aceitar ela](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/30452) para fechar o tópico :)

Answer (score 0):

As listas `lista_original` e `lista_corrigida`, não possuem o mesmo comprimento, sendo que a `lista_original` possui 18 itens e a `lista_corrigida` possui 20 itens, um outro erro que ocorre no seu sistema é o `for` com `range(23)` fora da quantidade de elementos, e um outro erro é o `lambda x`, ou seja, você está utilizando `x`, que seria a variável do número da `range`, por isso que ocorre o erro que você mencionou `python TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`.

### Código

A `lista_corrigida` possui dois elementos que não tem na `lista_original`, que seria *PERNAMBUCO* e *PIAUI*, com base nisso eu adicionei esses elementos na `lista_original` e troquei o `range(23) para range(20)` e alterei o `lambda` para receber valor diferente do `x` (variável da range)

```
import pandas as pd

lista_original = ['ACREERONDONIA','AMAZONASERORAIMA','CEARA','ESPIRITOSANTO','GOIAS','MARANHAO','MATOGROSSO','MATOGROSSODOSUL','MINASGERAIS','OFEDERALETOCANTINS','PARAEAMAPA','PARAIBA','PARANA','PERNAMBUCO','PIAUI', 'RIODEJANEIRO','RIOGRANDEDONORTE','RIOGRANDEDOSUL','SANTACATARINA','SAOPAULO']
lista_corrigida = ['ACRE E RONDÔNIA','AMAZONAS E RORAIMA','CEARÁ','ESPÍRITO SANTO','GOIÁS','MARANHÃO','MATO GROSSO','MATO GROSSO DO SUL','MINAS GERAIS','DISTRITO FEDERAL E TOCANTINS','PARA E AMAPÁ','PARAÍBA','PARANÁ','PERNAMBUCO','PIAUÍ','RIO DE JANEIRO','RIO GRANDE DO NORTE','RIO GRANDE DO SUL','SANTA CATARINA','SÃO PAULO']

df_dados_txt = pd.DataFrame({'LOCAL': lista_original})

for x in range(20):
    df_dados_txt['LOCAL'] = df_dados_txt['LOCAL'].apply(lambda local: local.replace(lista_original[x], lista_corrigida[x]))
```

#### Resultado

DataFrame com os valores da `lista_original`

### [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

DataFrame com os valores certos

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Você pode comprimir todos os seus `apply`s transformando os 2 arrays em um **dict** e usando o comando `.map` do pandas, desta forma:

```
lista_dict = dict(zip(lista_original, lista_corrigida))
df_dados_txt['LOCAL'] = df_dados_txt['LOCAL'].map(lista_dict)
```

O comando `.map` vai buscar pelas ocorrências chaves do dicionário (lista_original) e substituir pelos valores do dicionário (lista_corrigida)